# Why is an API User with R/W access to a lookup field, getting an INVALID_FIELD error?

Tags: soql, security

My API user makes the following query in Salesforce via the Standard REST API. They have Read / Edit privileges on the Contact__c field and Modify All on the Channel__c object. **They do not have access to the Contact object**

```
SELECT Id, Contact__c FROM Channel__c LIMIT 1
```

They get this error:

> INVALID_FIELD: SELECT Id, Contact__c FROM Channel__c ^ ERROR at Row:1:Column:12 No such column 'Contact__c' on entity 'Channel__c'. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 2):

I believe it is a key: **They do not have access to the Contact object**

> The user will require at least 'Read' access to the object in which the lookup field is referencing to see the lookup field.

Resources:

- https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000312790&type=1

Comment: Yep - that's why i bolded that part. It makes sense, but was hoping there was something else i could do to get around the issue